# Wildfly 10 Duplicate Log Messages

Tags: wildfly

I do not understand why I get duplicate messages in my Wildfly 10 log file.  Here is a tiny sample:

```
2016-10-12 11:43:34,320 WARN  [com.getmoremath.entities.Restore] (default task-31) Can't deserialize non-existent problem
...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/10/12 11:43:34 | [0m[33m11:43:34,320 WARN  [com.getmoremath.entities.Restore] (default task-31) Can't deserialize non-existent problem
```

This does not happen when I run my EAR app locally via Eclipse, but does happen when I run it on my remote server.  The two deployments (local and remote) have identical standalone.conf logging subsytems.

So I guess there is some extra configuration tucked away on the server that turns jvm logging on and somehow directs it to the same file as my Wildfly configured logging?  Weird.  Any ideas?

As a further clue, the remote logging sometimes creates multiple files on the same day, even though my standalone logging configuration is set to only rotate per day.  I get extra files with names like "server.log.1" and "server.log.2"

Here's the standalone for logging:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
```

Thanks for looking at this!

Josh

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, you packaged some logging-configuration/libraries within your EAR.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.  I did find that my EAR contained a Log4j.jar, but no extra configurations, and removing the jar didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `stdout` is being piped to the file. You can remove the `CONSOLE` handler from the `ROOT` logger.

I'd also suggest not piping `stdout` to the `server.log` as well. It should likely go to it's own file.